# ajax post working on chrome but not working on firefox and safari

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I've encountered an issue where a jquery ajax post method works on chrome but does not work on safari or firefox. I've looked through all the other similar posts and they don't solve the problem. Whenever I run the ajax code, it just returns the entire HTML of the page the form is found on.

Here's my javascript:

```js
$("#piece-form").submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    // gets which submit button was clicked
    var selectedButton = $(this).find("input[type=submit]:focus");
    var url = selectedButton.attr("name");
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax
    (
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data == "Success!")
                {
                    $("#error-box").css("display", "none");
                    $("#success-box").html("Success! Publishing...");
                    $("#success-box").css("display", "block");
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#success-box").css("display", "none");
                    $("#error-box").html(data);
                    $("#error-box").css("display", "block");
                }
            }
        }
    )
});
```

No matter the content of the PHP file the function points to, it doesn't work as planned. I've tried making a PHP file with a single echo line and I still run into the same problem. I've implemented an error block in the ajax as well and it returns nothing. I also don't receive an error in the console other than: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. For more help [http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/"](http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/%22) in Firefox

Edit: I've added contentType:false and it still isn't functioning properly on Firefox and Safari

Comment: Try adding `async: true`. Check if that works

Comment: @Anvay I've tried that, no dice

Comment: @LelioFaieta — You're completely wrong. The submit event fires before the default behaviour happens. The form submission can be prevented with `preventDefault` on a submit event. Using a submit event for this sort of thing is best practise.

Comment: This is just a guess. . If you have no specific need to use `processData` try to remove it and see if that works!

Comment: @Ingus if I remove processData the form fails to submit altogether for some reason. At least it's a different response haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

The error is in the following line of code:

```js
 var selectedButton = $(this).find("input[type=submit]:focus");
var url = selectedButton.attr("name");
```

For some reason, Firefox and Safari don't properly get the value of "selectedButton" (although Chrome does) resulting in the url variable being incorrectly set. In order to circumvent this, I did the following:

```
 $(".piece-button").click(function (){
    url = $(this).attr("name");
})
```

I needed the submittedButton method because I had two submit buttons for the form and was trying to find which one was clicked. This alternate method does that and is transferrable across all three browsers I have tested. This may not be an optimal solution to the two button submit issue but it worked for me and now the ajax works without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrap your code in document ready?
Also as much as i know now it is correct to use on():

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#piece-form").on('submit', function(e){
        //your main code here
    });
});
```

For now it does not looks like there would be any issue. ..

Comment: Yeah, my whole javascript is wrapped in a $(document).ready(). Unfortunately this is not the solution

Answer (score 0):

Though you have got the solution but from interest I am sharing mine as I have just encountered same problem and got the workaround by adding `event.preventDefault();` after `success`. Example code is given

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('form').on('submit', function(event) {

        $.ajax({
                data: {
                    name: $('#nameInput').val(),
                    email: $('#emailInput').val()
                },
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/post_for_db',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    $("body").html(data);
                    // This will navigate to your preferred location
                    document.location = '/render_table_from_db';
                },
        event.preventDefault(); // solution is this for me
    });
});
```